# Histogram with equal area bins in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, bins

I would like to create a histogram in `ggplot2` where each bin has the same number of points and **all** bins have the same area. In base R we could do the following:

```r
set.seed(123)
x <- rnorm(100)
hist(x, breaks = quantile(x, 0:10 / 10))
```

[image]

When I try this in `ggplot` with `scale_x_continuous` and setting breaks like `hist` it returns the following:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = data.frame(x), aes(x = x)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y = after_stat(density)), bins = 10) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=quantile(x, 0:10 / 10))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-01-05 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Why is this returning a different output? So I was wondering if anyone knows how to create a histogram with equal area bins using `ggplot` like in the base option above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanted the same output as the base R hist, you can just extract the values from the object and draw it yourself.

```
set.seed(123)
x <- rnorm(100)
hh <- hist(x, breaks = quantile(x, 0:10 / 10))

data.frame(
  left=head(hh$breaks,-1), right=tail(hh$breaks, -1),
  height=hh$density
) |> 
  ggplot() + 
  aes(xmin=left, xmax=right, ymin=0, ymax=height) + 
  geom_rect(fill="lightgray", color="black")
```

[image]